# Little o and omega notation

Tags: algorithm

If () = Ω(())⁡then () = (())?
then will it be Ω(())=(())?
I am little confused if the statement can be always true or always not. or sometimes true.

Comment: Are you asking if Big Omega implies Little o?

Answer (score 0):

By definition, if `f(n) \in Omega(g(n))`, then `lim f(n)/g(n) > 0` when `n` goes to infinity. But, for little oh, we have `lim f(n) / g(n) = 0` when `n` goes to infinity. Hence, they are completely opposite to each other. It means if `f(n) \in Omega(n)`, we can conclude that `f(n)` cannot be in `o(g(n))` and in the opposite direction, if `f(n) \in o(g(n))`, `f(n)` cannot be in `\Omega(g(n))`.

Answer (score -1):

The statement 'If () = Ω(())⁡then () = (())' is false.

[Analysis of algorithms](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/analysis-of-algorithems-little-o-and-little-omega-notations/)